# How to use Lucene/Solr in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, lucene

My project is about an online Mobile Shopping site.

I created search controller,and I use WHERE LIKE to do that:

```
def create
    @result = Phone.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{get}%" ])
    render :index
end

private
   def get
      params[:keyword]
   end
```

Now I want to exchange to Full-text-search.So have some gem to do that ? And how to code to searching by full-text-search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [elastic-search-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) gem for implementing full text search in your Rails application.

In your `app/models/phone.rb:`

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end

Phone.import
```

Then, in your controller:

```
@result = Phone.search('foobar').records
```

Here is a good tutorial on [Getting Started with Elasticsearch on Rails](http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/409843?referrer_id=948927) that would help you. Another good SitePoint article that will help you get going is [Full-Text Search in Rails with ElasticSearch](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/).